# Qt configuration for using Pleora Libs and include

Tags: c++, qt, gige-sdk

i am having troubles in setting up the eviroment for develop a simple application using pleora SDK, i have include succedfully the libs and .h files in the .pro file , but when i just include a .h file e.g.:

```
//main.c
#include <PvBuffer.h>
```

i just get only errors in the compiling windows.
the compiling is just a test that i do to verify the well execution a single include statement.

There any more else steps that i am not seing?
any hint or guide will be well received!
PD:
the .pro file is like that:

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = pleora
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Pleora Technologies Inc/eBUS SDK/Includes"
LIBS += "C:/Program Files (x86)/Pleora Technologies Inc/eBUS SDK/Libraries/*.lib"
```

Comment: Post the exact errors and make sure your file PvBuffer.h is present in the include path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi well i was tryng to set the lib and the includes files under the Eclipse CDT usign MingGw, feels like it doesn support this kind of compiler, well back to MSVS c++ 2008 and setting automaticle, work fine and smooth.
Pleora doesnt support Gcc compiler.

Comment: this is absolute it true!, i have to download msvc express and set the compiler to the msvc, then set the lib and the includes files from pleora, this was using Eclipse/CDT/c++/Qt plugin